# statistical test of data to y=x line

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, matlab, descriptive-statistics

[image]My question is about how to show if my data is better fitted to the y=x line. I calculate my x and y using different ratios so for ratio A, I get x1 and y1 while for ratio B, I get x2 and y2.

```
%1st figure (left) 
figure(); subplot(1,2,1);
x1=[36;36;37;37;36;34;33;33;25;38;37;37;34;32;31;31;26;36;34;36;33;35;36;36;36;38;37;36;35;36;34;34;33;30;37;39;37;36;33;30;27;35;40;37;37;37;37;39;37;40;40;38;38;35];
y1=[37;38;39;39;42;38;40;39;29;36;40;40;35;31;36;37;31;38;37;34;34;33;34;36;35;34;36;36;34;34;33;38;36;36;39;38;38;34;37;35;31;36;37;38;39;37;36;37;38;39;40;39;38;35];
plot(x1,y1,'b.', 'markersize',20)
set(gca,'xlim',[20 45],'ylim',[20 45],'FontSize',13);grid on; hold on;
b = 0; h = 20:45;
plot(h, h+b,'r');
%2nd figure (right)
subplot(1,2,2);
x2=[38;38;39;39;38;36;34;34;21;40;40;38;35;32;30;30;22;38;36;38;34;37;38;37;38;40;39;37;37;38;35;35;34;29;39;41;39;37;34;29;24;38;41;39;40;39;40;41;39;42;43;40;40;36];
y2=[36;37;37;37;40;36;38;37;22;32;38;38;31;24;33;34;25;37;34;30;30;28;30;31;30;29;32;31;29;28;27;35;32;32;39;35;35;29;33;31;25;35;36;37;38;36;34;35;35;37;38;37;34;31];
plot(x2,y2,'k*', 'markersize',10);
set(gca,'xlim',[20 45],'ylim',[20 45],'FontSize',13);grid on; hold on;
b = 0; h = 20:45;
plot(h, h+b,'r');
```

I can tell that ratio A (figure left) is better fitted to the y=x line than ratio B (figure right). But how can I statistically show this?

Comment: Concordance correlation measures agreement, i.e. the extent to which $y = x$ in your notation. In addition to the thread suggested as duplicate, other threads can be identified by searching the forum for mentions of "concordance correlation".

Comment: I get concordance correlation of 0.533 and 0.477 respectively for these graphs.  Often a plot of $y - x$ versus $(y  + x)$ or equivalently $(y + x)/2$ is helpful.

Comment: @NickCox I was just reading about the Concordance Correlation coefficient... From what I understand, the equation to calculate CCC = 2cov/(var+var+(mean_diff)2) - to write very simply measures agreement between two variables as a departure from perfect linearity of the y=x type, where 
    ρc=1−(Expected orthogonal squared distance from the diagonal x=y/Expected orthogonal squared distance from the diagonal x=y assuming independence)
where a correlation of 1 means it is well fitted to the y=x line.

Comment: I agree with the numbers you got from the CCC... meaning the first value of 0.53 is a better fit to y=x line rather than the other... I assume I can subset the data to have certain values fitting much better to the y=x line.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about subsetting but otherwise you seem on target.

Comment: yup i did not explain that, my mistake... I could put a z data and plot that too (in this case depth). then, instead of all blue, you will get a range of colours indicating depth... So I can say that certain z values (say for example 0-200m), ratio A is better for the x1 & y1 values with a higher CCC.... then z(500-1000m), ratio B is better with x2 & y2 with a higher CCC.... and so on.... because right now, I say ratio A is best with CCC 0.53 but it is from 0-2000m.

Comment: I am not clear if you are asking for extra advice, but (a) I don't think you have defined A and B  except as names associated with the two graphs; I don't see definitions of these ratios (b) if you have extra variables you may need a more detailed analysis looking for structure in $y - x$ or $\log y - \log x$ as possibly dependent on others.